# Generate pdf plot in Flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I'd like to create a small app in `Flask` which:
1. Allows the user to upload data, in `csv`
2. Does stuff to the data (in this example, nothing will be done)
3. Plot results
4. Allow the user to download a plot of the results as pdf.

Code so far:

#### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_svg import FigureCanvasSVG

import io
import csv
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/transform', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def transform_view():
    """ process data and render plot on the fly.
    """
    # GET input csv 
    f = request.files['input_file']
    if not f:
        return "Main input file not found!"

    # Read uploaded data as a Stream into a dataframe. 
    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    contents = []
    for row in csv_input:
        contents.append(row)
    d0 = pd.DataFrame(data=contents[1:], columns=contents[0])

    # Change to numeric columns
    d0[["col1", "col2"]] = d0[["col1", "col2"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

    # Plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    bplot = ax.boxplot([d0["col1"], d0["col2"]])

    # Print out plot as pdf?
    #output = io.BytesIO()
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h3>Upload input file (csv)</h3>
        <input type="file" name="input_file" id="input_file">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Process & Download" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### sample_input.csv

```
col1,col2
1,5
2,6
3,7
9,10
6,11
```

So I can generate the pdf with `matplotlib`, but I'm not sure how to return this as a pdf to the user (the last step). I'm not married to `matplotlib`; if there are other plotting libraries which can return plots as pdf, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (I don't have flask installed on this workstation) but you can save the figure as a pdf by giving the correct extension

```
fig.savefig('/tmp/some_unique_string.pdf')
```

and then serve the file with [`send_from_directory`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory)

```
from flask import send_from_directory
send_from_directory('/tmp', 'some_unique_string.pdf')
```

---

Some unsolicited advice:

1. You can read a csv with `pandas.read_csv`. This works with a file path or an IO stream and will change numeric columns to an appropriate numeric type automatically.
2. If you want to switch to a different backend, you need to do so before importing `pyplot`.

Specifically:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What if there are multiple users? I can automatically generate new output filenames with sequence numbers with something like `os.listdir`, but I hope that Flask automatically knows to send the right file to the right user upon clicking a download button?

Comment: Use the uuid module to generate random strings.